# Yii2 -- Pretty Url -- Domain to Controller/Action with parameters

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, pretty-urls

What will be the rules for my pretty url if I have the following scenario:

links like this where parameters may vary.

```
 domain/?bt=<token>&e=<email>
```

or

```
 domain/?lt=<token>&e=<email>
```

then should be processed in a controller/action. ie. mycontroller/get

Also, parameters should be accessible by $_GET inside the action.

Comment: whta do you mean with bt or lt?   .. what's the difference between the two sample ?...  show a real sample of what you need ..

Comment: http://localhost:8080/myapplication/web/index.php?r=open-msg/get&bt=123&e=myemail@gmail.com 
or 
http://localhost:8080/myapplication/web/index.php?r=click/get&bt=456&e=myemail@gmail.com

bt and lt are just parameters.
with that links, I want it to be processed to mycontroller/get

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way  is based on the use of urlHelper

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

$myUrl  = Url::to(['your_controller/your_action', 'bt' => 123, 'e' => 'myemail@gmail.com']);
```

Using  the urlHelper function Url::to .. the url you need  is properly formed depending of the urlManager configuration you have set in your config file 
and the param a manager  as show in the sample like entry in an array.

The post or get method is related  to the type of metho you have in your ulr call if not other values are specified  the url is formed  as a get
and you can obtain the values you need  in `$_GET['bt']` and `$_get['e']`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-url.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Comment: Thank you scaisEdge but it didn't fit as a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '' => 'call-backs/get',
            'unsubscribes' => 'unsubscribes/get',
        ],
    ],
```

@scaisEdge, thank you for answering my question. maybe my question isn't that clear but this is the solution I made for my question after a hard find of clues and tips online.

All I wanted was that when a user clicks on a link, hitting the main page/main domain, it will go to my yii project (intended to be a webservice or an API like one) then will be handled by a precise controller and action.

```
'' => 'call-backs/get'
```

the code above answers the question. Cheers.